# NoMethodError when I try to access localhost:3000/home

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to access the 'home' page of my Rails app by going to localhost:3000/home

When I try the link above, however, I get the below error message --- however this doesn't make sense to me because 'category' is just a parameter for an order. Order has a category, store, items and other parameters.

My code is below. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Showing /Users/fk/tenence_ai/app/views/tenence/home.html.erb where line #49 raised:

undefined method `category' for #<Order:0x007f8ed99c8500>
Extracted source (around line #49):

47  <div>
48   <%= form_for :order, url: orders_path do |f| %>
49   <%= f.text_field :category,:id=> 'category',:style=>'display:none' %>
```

**ORDERS CONTROLLER**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json
    def show
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
        @idx = Order.last.id
        render json: @order
    end
    def create
        @order = Order.new(order_params)
        @order.save
    end
    def edit
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end
    def update
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
      @order.update(order_params)
    end
   respond_to :html, :json
    private
        def order_params
            params.require(:order).permit(:address,:store,:name,:items,:category,:status,:total,{:item => []},{:price => []})
        end
end
```

**ORDER MODEL**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**RELEVANT MIGRATION**

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :address
      t.string :store
      t.text :items

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: does "rails/rake routes" show home as a list route?

Comment: Do you have `category` column? Please show also your migrations please. Thanks!

Comment: @hikmatyar, check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to add `category` field:

Adding in `params.require` is good but you also need to add `attr_accessor :category` in your model.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :category
end
```

`attr_accessor` can be used for values you don't want to store in the database directly and that will only exist for the life of the object.